# How to tweet from within an application using cordova?

Tags: cordova, twitter, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am looking for a cordova plugin that will allow me to tweet from an account related to my application only, not he users.

To make this clearer, take for example a game app. The user gets a new high score in the game. Now I want to tweet their high score but not from their twitter account, rather from the twitter associated to the game itself. How can this be done? I looked into many twitter plugins but all of them were associated to the users twitter account which is what I don't want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped to ionic since its built over Cordova. The problem is if I use Cordova only, my twitter keys are exposed (except if I use my own server in between twitter and the browser). Ionic uses Angular js.

Answer (score 0):

It is really pretty simple, using Twitter's REST API.  Just use jQuery.Post() method to call Twitter's status update API (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update).  There is a little more to it, you will have to do authentication first.  But it really is a simple javascript call to post a status update; no plugin necessary.

Comment: thank you for helping out! I did look into it however, there are two types of authentications. According to https://dev.twitter.com/oauth , I think I should be using Application-user authentication although I will be the user (application owner). I read the link you sent me however, I dont know how to apply it to the $.post parameters -->( url, [data], [callback], [type] ). What will I fill the data part with? is it the string i want to tweet?

Comment: take for example the post request: POST
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk. You have the status there, is it supposed to represent the data part in the comment above? Also the symbols are in hex, how am i supposed to deal with that? I appreciate acknowledge on this topic since I'm new to http and the twitter api and the docs examples were not enough.. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want to tweet a score to the twitter account of the game ? If that's the case, I would say, just use the share feature of the platform you are working on and share the score in the tweet.
Of Course, you need to have the twitter app on the phone/device you are using the game app.

Comment: No I dont want the user to share anything and I dont want to get their twitter account involved. Its an app that people use, and if the user follows certain steps I want to tweet to the applications account (my account). Having the twitter app will be unnecessary since I will use the post method and I dont want to open twitter.